# Drift and diffusion in semiconductors

Tags: semiconductors

I understand that what's diffusion and what's drift current but what I don know is how I identify whether a semiconductor is diffusion or drift based? Let's say bjt MOSFET and diode as example. They all have diffusion and drift property for me which makes me confused

---

Thanks! That clears my doubts. but from my notes it says bjt is diffusion based which mKes me confuse and MOSFET  is drift based. Can I know how we know which will dominant to the other?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A semiconductor is not diffusion or drift-based, those are two phenomena always taking place in the same semiconductor. Considering electrons as carriers (but the same can be said for holes), the current density in a semiconductor can be expressed by the drift-diffusion transport equation:

$$
\vec{J}_n=q\mu_nn\vec{E} + qD_n\vec{\nabla}n
$$
where \$q\$ is the elctron charge, \$\mu_n\$ the electrons mobility, \$n\$ the electron concentration and \$D_n\$ the diffusion coefficient. Thus, according to which term in the sum dominates the other you could say that a certain current is produced by diffusion or drift, but that's a matter of the ՝՝circumstances'', it's not the semiconductor which is diffusion or drift-based.

If you applied a strong electric field, the drift term would dominate; if no field is applied then the current is due only to the \$n\$ concentration gradient.

Hoping that what I said is clear enough, I want to make one final note: don't be fooled into thinking that without an electric field you would obtain a constant current depending only on how you doped your semiconductor; when electrons start to flow into the domain with less \$n\$ concentration, they ՝՝leave behind'' positively ionized atoms, which contributes in generating a potential difference and thus an electric field, until the diffusion term is compensated and there is no net flux of carriers.

Comment: Thanks! That clears my doubts. but from my notes it says bjt is diffusion based which mKes me confuse and MOSFET is drift based. Can I know how we know which will dominant to the other ?thanks . Picture is provided above

Comment: That depends on the structure of the device. What I said holds in general for semiconductors, but electron devices are more complex than that and according to their structure and working principle you can tell if diffusion or drift is exploited. Of course, this means studying and understanding how each device works, thus I don't have a general rule to tell you; maybe someone more expert and knowledgeable than me can clear your doubts. P.S. in general it's not appropriate to create an answer to comment. If you told me what your notes said, I'd have trusted you ;)

Comment: Please, @M.L, if you find the answer useful, at least upvote it. That's how this site works.

Comment: @M.L. valuating the equation as given in David`s answer you will see that it is the electric field that matters primarily.  And which quantity is the cause of this field? It is the applied base-emitter voltage Vbe (and NOT the base current). Hence, the 3rd statement in the copy of the book you have provided is wrong!. Please note that, unfortunately, there are some other books which also contain similar errors - perhaps due to historical reasond. But, undoubtly, the BJT is a voltage-controlled device (remember the working principle of a pn diode).

Answer (score 0):

The current flowing due to the concentration gradient is called diffusion.During the formation of barrier potential the p holes go to n side whereas the n electrons go to the p side to form immobile ions,this is due to concentration difference.Thus BJT is a device which is current controlled and current is duffusion.Whereas Mosfet as we know works on the variation of Vgs which is voltage controlled and there is no such thing as concentration gradient in this case.Whatever carrier current is due to majority charges which flow under the attraction of potential applied ie the drift current.